# adding extra td element

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have this table.

```
 <tr>
        <td style="padding-left: 25pt;"><font style="background-color: white" color="black"> Hello</font></td>
        <td style="padding-left: 25pt;"><font style="background-color: white" color="black">Bye</font></td>
</tr>
```

but I want to add an extra td element at the end so it looks like this:

```
<tr>
        <td style="padding-left: 25pt;"><font style="background-color: white" color="black"> Hello</font></td>
        <td style="padding-left: 25pt;"><font style="background-color: white" color="black">Bye</font></td>
        <td>1</td>


</tr>
```

I am using htmlAgilityPack, but the examples online that I have looked don't exactly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this may help you

```
string data = @"<tr><td style='padding-left: 25pt;'><font style='background-color: white' color='black'> Hello</font></td><td style='padding-left: 25pt;'><font style='background-color: white' color='black'>Bye</font></td></tr>";
string rowToAppend = "<td>1</td>";
var html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(data);
var table = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("tr").FirstOrDefault();
var node = HtmlNode.CreateNode(rowToAppend);
table.AppendChild(node);
data += table.OuterHtml;
```

Comment: will this work even though there are two td elements? how will it know to insert the new td element at the end?

Comment: it is creating new node, so it is always add in end